# AdaptiveCards with PostBack button

Tags: bots, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to replace a HeroCard that has multiple CardAction buttons.  I would like to use AdaptiveCards, however, I don't see any documentation that states how to enable postBack from an AdaptiveCard button.  I see open browser, and what not, but no postBack.

Is this supported yet?

```
        var cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        var yesAction = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Yes",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Yes"
        };
        cardButtons.Add(yesAction);

        var noAction = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Nope",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "No, I'll try it"
        };
        cardButtons.Add(noAction);

        var plCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = $"Are you sure?",
            Buttons = cardButtons
        };
```

Comment: Action.Http opens a url, my buttons don't, they are shortcuts back to the bot service.

Comment: I solved this by using SuggestedActions and catching the text of the button on the form validator

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SubmitAction`?

```
var noAction = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "Nope",
    Type = SubmitAction.TYPE,
    Title = "No, I'll try it"
};
```

Comment: using the visualizer at http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/ i have tried all the different buttons, but not sure if my configuration was wrong for one of them or not.  Also, not sure that these buttons work within facebook messenger, as none of the buttons display for the Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Yeah, the buttons do not render in Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

This code renders correctly, even seems to send information back to the bot. But still cannot figure out how to read the data back on the resuming function:

```
var card = new AdaptiveCard();
card.Body.Add(
    new ColumnSet() {
        Columns = new List<Column>() {
            new Column() {
                SelectAction = new SubmitAction() { Data = 3, Title = "Good" },
                Items = new List<CardElement>() { new Image() { Url = GeneralStrings.Feedback03 } }
            },
            new Column() {
                SelectAction = new SubmitAction() { Data = 2, Title = "Average" },
                Items = new List<CardElement>() { new Image() { Url = GeneralStrings.Feedback02 } }
            },
            new Column() {
                SelectAction = new SubmitAction() { Data = 1, Title = "Bad" },
                Items = new List<CardElement>() { new Image() { Url = GeneralStrings.Feedback01 } }
            }
        }
    });

var attachemnt = new Attachment() { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = card };

var message = context.MakeMessage();
message.Attachments.Add(attachemnt);

await context.PostAsync(message);
context.Wait<Activity>(this.AfterAskFeedback);
```